# Change image on a map android

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to change the colors of the areas of Google Maps.

Here's an example

[image]

Is there a way I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use `Polygon` for draw shape.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is GroundOverlay.
You can overlay an image for particular area over the map (under markers, polygons, polylines).
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay

**update: How to create a ground overlay layer?**

For example: you want to fill this building as green.
[image]

You need to get latitude and longitude pairs for two positions : southwest and northeast.

[image]

Then create an image with transparent (such as PNG format).
[image]

After that, you need to create a ground overlay in your code.

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(
    new LatLng(....),       // South west corner
    new LatLng(....)      // North east corner
);
GroundOverlayOptions myBuilding = new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_building))
    .positionFromBounds(bounds);
```

You should see the target building is painted as green.
[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the color all area? That is StyledMapType, but StyledMapType is not available in Google Maps Android API v2 yet.

Comment: No, I want to color a particular building.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay#use_latlngbounds_to_position_an_image

Comment: If you want to ask me how to get the latitude & longitude from map, go to http://maps.google.com, and right click of mouse. You will see the context menu. Then choose "What is here?". You can see the latitude, longitude.

Comment: Ok, So it would be the angle southweast of the image the southweat point?